# How to configuration Oracle connection pool in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, connection-pooling

I want to configure the number of connection pools in ActiveMQ for the Oracle database. What should I do for this purpose? My current configuration is as follows:

```xml
<bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1521:hmdservicename"/>
   <property name="username" value="hmd"/>
   <property name="password" value="hmd"/>
   <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

My ActiveMQ version is 5.16.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the details for configuring `BasicDataSource` in the [DBCP documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html). You can configure the maximum number of connections in the pool using the `maxTotal` property, e.g.:

```xml
<bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1521:hmdservicename"/>
   <property name="username" value="hmd"/>
   <property name="password" value="hmd"/>
   <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
   <property name="maxTotal" value="25"/>
</bean>
```